# Print 6,5,4,3,2 characters separated by a new line in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

Using a `for` loop, how can I print the following ouput into a console:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
```

*Side point:* Out of interest, is it possible to do the above without a `for` loop?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Sound like homework....

Comment: @DanielSanchez It is actually, but I've tried all I could, asked fellow students and cannot get it :(

Comment: you can do every loop without a `for`: there are other forms of loops, some equivalent to `for` like `while` and `do..while`, and then there is recursion which can do even more than (stackless) loops can

Comment: You should try it on your own, then if you face trouble post what you have tried and we will be glad to help. 
You are not going to learn if you copy past from others.

Comment: Strange, if you know how to do it in python, there should be no problem to replicate it in C++.
Try some C++ tutorials on line, or just post what you have tried up to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (int i=6; i>1; i--)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            cout<<"*";

        cout<<endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
```

Comment: These are two nested loops. I think that he wants to use only one loop.

Comment: @Jepessen Two is fine

Answer (score 1):

How about a while loop: http://ideone.com/ezk6Ax

```
string s(6, '*');
while (s.size() > 1) {
    cout << s << endl;
    s.pop_back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string s("*******");
  for (int i = s.size() - 1; i > 1; i--) {
    std::cout << s.substr(0, i) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10924920bc66f91d

Comment: .substr() is a heavy operation for such a simple problem.

Comment: Simpler than create a lambda function. Even if heavy it does the work properly.

Answer (score 1):

my variant:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 6; i >= 2; --i) {
        std::generate_n(
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""), i,
            []() { return '*'; });
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```